# Filtering a Get-printer variable output

Tags: powershell

I need to get all the printers named with a printer name starting with `P0`

I'm new to PowerShell and the command `get-printer` did not support my syntax for the filtering. My output variable is empty.

I have tried filtering the command results and tried filtering the content of the results variable with all printers without success.

```bsh
$PrinterList = Get-Printer -ComputerName "PrintServer" -Filter {name -like 'P0'}
```

Or

```bsh
$PrinterList = Get-Printer -ComputerName "PrintServer"

$PrinterSort = $PrinterList.Name | Where-Object {$PrinterList.Name -Like "P0"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the other answer, you need to include one or more [wildcard characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-6) in your string (e.g `*` for 0 or more characters, or `?` for a single character).

You can also simplify your code to use a wildcard in the `-Name` parameter on the cmdlet directly:

```
$PrinterList = Get-Printer -ComputerName "PrintServer" -Name "P0*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a wildcard for your `-like`, e.g. `name -like 'P0*'`

This should work with both of your solutions.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me and for your answer, i tried this way and it's giving me an error ```PowerShell $PrinterList = Get-Printer -ComputerName "PrintServer" -Filter name -like 'P0*' ```

Comment: @AMIGA `Get-printer` doesn't have `-filter` parameter use this:
`$PrinterList = Get-Printer -ComputerName "PrintServer"`

`$PrinterSort = $PrinterList.Name | Where-Object {$PrinterList.Name -Like "P0*"}`

Comment: Thanks Tesla, i tried your syntax and it's exporting all the printers in the variable without filtering on "P0*" I have checked the best answer :) Thanks again